# Negative auxiliar verbs answers

Tags: inversion

When we use a structure like, *Neither I nor he is going to...*; example:

> Richard: Are you ready for dating Joshua, Sarah?
>
> Sarah: Neither I nor he is going to date each other any more!
>
> Richard: you won't?

Is it correct to answer a negative statement in this way or I am wrong here?

Comment: "Neither I nor he is going to date each other" doesn't sound right to me. For one thing, it almost always sounds better to put the pronoun "I" in last place in a list, so "Neither he nor I" would be better than "Neither I nor he". For another thing, the "each other" doesn't seem to work, as it usually comes after a plural verb rather than a singular. The fact that the verb is singular also seems a problem to me, as it's logically impossible for only one of you to date the other. Why not just say "We are not going to date each other any more"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Neither I nor he **are** going to date each other anymore.
>   *we are not dating each other any more*

might get used, grouping the "I am", "he is" as "we are". However, the condition can also be said as

> Neither I nor he is...
>   Neither he nor I am...

where the verb is governed by the final noun/pronoun, though this may lead to certain formations sounding awkward.  Since Sarah is talking about something in the future "will be dating" might be simplest to use.

By placing "I" first, Sarah is giving emphasis on herself.  In school we are usually taught to put reference to ourselves at the end of a list for politeness.  Obviously, Sarah is not happy.

Richard's response to Sarah should be

> You're not *(going to date each other anymore)*?
>
> Sarah: Neither I nor he will be dating each other anymore.
>   Richard: You won't?
>                 You're not?

Comment: "Neither he nor I are"? Can you provide a citation that advises this type of agreement? It conflicts with the general rule that verbs after disjunct singular nouns are, or are "supposed" to be, singular (as in "Neither Nancy nor Tom is going to the party"). See here for more discussion: [Controversy over verb choice in “neither you nor I {is/am/are} in control”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122969)